# Nightwatch parallel testing

Tags: selenium, saucelabs, nightwatch.js, circleci

I am trying to run several nightwatch tests in parallel on sauce labs via test workers. When the tests are run only the assertions from the first file are run and the rest say 0 assertions failed, 0 passed. The first file runs all of its assertions.

Comment: I suppose that doesn’t happen locally, is that right?

Comment: the only way i have been running tests is on saucelabs so not sure, but whenever i run them only 1 of the 4 files that are running actually runs the test. The rest test 0 assertions and just end right away.

Comment: actually when i run them locally with gulp nightwatch the same thing happens. All 4 browsers open but they all close immediately except 1 which runs all the tests normally.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the reference, but please have a look at [this github issue](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/99)